# aggregating factors of different length dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate, find-occurrences

I have various dataframes like:

```
Var1 "Bananas" "Apples" "Oranges" 
Freq    "2"      "2"       "1"              


Var2 "Bananas" "Carrots" "Strawberries" "Apples"
Freq    "3"       "2"        "3"          "4"
```

and as output I'd like one dataframe / table / something similar giving the occurrences of each input dataframe, including the 0 occurrences in a nice overview. So something like:

```
Var     "Bananas" "Apples" "Oranges" "Carrots" "Strawberries"
Sample1   "2"        "2"      "1"       "0"         "0"
Sample2   "3"        "4"      "0"       "2"         "3"
```

I cannot quite figure out any solution, especially since data.frames do not allow for different lengths.

Comment: Have you looked at `merge`?

Comment: Those don't look like data frames.  A reproducible example would be swell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take note that `NA` and `0` mean very different things. Have a look at the help file to `?dplyr::join`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- data.frame(Var1 =c("Bananas", "Apples", "Oranges"), 
           Freq =c(2,2,1))
df2 <- data.frame(Var1 =c("Bananas", "Carrots",
                          "Strawberries", "Apples"), 
                  Freq =c(3,2,3,4))
full_join(df1,df2, by = "Var1")
```

Comment: It is included in my original answer to look at  ?dplyr::join, but I edited the function call to specify the library, but I guess I could have been more clear.

Comment: `::` loads the library, but I do get your point. It is probably more accessible to a beginner which is apparent from the question.

Comment: thanks. this solved it for two dataframes.

Is there a possible extension to multiple ones ?

Comment: Yes, take a look at plyr::join_all, or Reduce. You are welcome to select or upvote this and close this question one.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at `?merge`:

```
set.seed(1234)
dat1 <- data.frame(var1 = LETTERS[1:5], freq = sample(1:100, 5))
dat2 <- data.frame(var2 = LETTERS[3:7], freq = sample(1:100, 5))

res <- merge(dat1, dat2, by.x = "var1", by.y = "var2", all = TRUE)
res[is.na(res)] <- 0
res
#   var1 freq.x freq.y
# 1    A     12      0
# 2    B     62      0
# 3    C     60     65
# 4    D     61      1
# 5    E     83     23
# 6    F      0    100
# 7    G      0     50
```

Comment: What if there are `NA`s in the data prior to merging?  You just changed *them* to `0` as well.

Comment: @RichardScriven Fair point -- I really just wanted to illustrate how `merge` might help the OP. If the OP clarifies their question, I'll either delete or update the answer.